AMD or NVIDIA. Which has better compatibility?
AMD Radeon RX 6600 GPU for Ubuntu Desktop 24.04
Looking around the internet there appears to be problems with AMD drivers.
I thought that the driver problem was mostly confined to NVIDIA.
At the moment I am using the NVIDIA GTX 960 GPU, and the fans are constantly full blast with the X.org driver.
Things are little bit stuttery with this driver.
But with the proprietary NVIDIA driver the resume function does not work.
It has been suggested to me that AMD GPU drivers have greater compatibility with Linux.
Can anyone give me some info about this ?

There's no clear winner in the competition between AMD and NVIDIA in Ubuntu, but here's a comparison.
AMD:

Open source drivers are included by default in Ubuntu.
Proprietary drivers can be installed for more features and performance, however they might not receive automatic software updates as the built-in AMD drivers do.

NVIDIA:

NVIDIA requires installing proprietary drivers for full functionality.
Ubuntu has an ubuntu-drivers program for automatically selecting and installing the most compatible proprietary NVIDIA graphics driver for your computer's NVIDIA graphics card with sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot
Ubuntu has a built-in Nouveau open source graphics driver that offers fallback capability when installed alongside the proprietary NVIDIA graphics drivers.
NVIDIA drivers from then official Ubuntu repositories are frequently updated and generally stable.
NVIDIA drivers may offer better performance for specific tasks that depend on the CUDA parallel computing platform and programming model created by NVIDIA.


Opinion:
In the beginning (14.04 for me!), before the nvidia drivers got an apt package the *.run (proprietary download) package had to be reinstalled after any kernel or xorg updates.
Nowadays the very latest version may be broken (i.e. causing trouble) at times, but other trouble has not emerged during the ten year period when I have been running nvidia GPU's (780, 1080, 2060 and now a laptop w 1660Ti, if I remember all correctly).
NOTE: As with ANY hardware and Linux; If you ponder on very recently released hardware, I recommend to pause a bit and make very sure it is supported and stable before you purchase. Regardless of creator/producer.
Can't tell about AMD:s.
